# C# Loop Through An Array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I am completely new to C#.  I am trying to loop through a short array, where the string elements in the array are placed at the end of a website search.  The code:

```
int n = 1;
string[] s = {"firstitem","seconditem","thirditem"}
int x = s.Max(); // note, from my research this should return the maximum value in the array, but this is the first error
x = x + 1

while (n < x)
{

      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.website.com/" + b[0]);

      b[]++; // this also generates an error "identifier expected"

}
```

My coding, logic or both are wrong.  Based on what I've read, I should be able to get the maximum value in an array (as an int), then add to the arrays value while a `WHILE` loop adds each value in the array at the end of the website (and then stops).  Note, that on the first error, I tried coding it differently, like the below:

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(s.Max);
```

However, it generates an overload error.  If I'm reading things correctly, `MAX` should find the maximum value in a sequence.

Comment: Your loop will never exit!  `while (n <= x)` will always be true since you don't change `x` or `n` in the body.  So it will loop forever.

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly?

Comment: Sorry, but almost everything in your code is wrong. Please read [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx)

Comment: You shouldnt use a while loop. @Anders Linden posted a good soloution.
In general you want your while loop to be:
while(n < s.Length)... n++;

Comment: You say that int x = s.Max(); generates the first error, but you don't say what the error is.

Comment: @NateHekman Thanks; I added a < only and incremented x to one above the maximum number in an array.

Comment: You're incrementing `x` outside of the loop though...

Comment: But `x` is still not changing *inside* your loop.  It's still an infinite loop.

Comment: b[]++ this souldn't even compile

Comment: int x = s.Max(); will not compile.  The Max value of an array of strings is a string, not an int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach(var str in s)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.website.com/" + str);
}
```

Comment: You should just use a regular for, as opposed to foreach, here.

Comment: Performance. In a foreach loop, you're creating a copy of the string when it's not necessary. Just grab it by it's index. Why create a copy of a string just to append it to another string?

Comment: Is not str just holding another reference? I like this way of writing so much that performance comes in second place. I actually would blame the runtime environment if it cannot optimize the code so it runs with equal efficiency.

Comment: This only loads the last item in the array.

Comment: @Yatrix that is incorrect, and I don't know why you would care about such a micro-optimisation in this code anyway.

Comment: Cant be, there is something else that has gone wrong then, try Console.WriteLine(str); in the loop. You will see that every string goes to the output window. (The one you open with ctrl w o).

Comment: Obviously, not for this instance, but in general, it's a good habit to get into

Comment: It is a good habit to write code with few characters if you ask me.

Comment: @Yatrix No, it's not. Readability is more important in 99.99% of cases, besides which: it's not any faster. `foreach` does *not* create a new copy of the strings.

Comment: Sorry, reference, not copy. That's my fault.

Comment: @Blorgbeard how is for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) { theString += arr[i];} not readable? It's just as readable, if your array is aptly named.

Comment: The browser window is reused, http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/everytime-opening-new-browser-window-t1232689.html

Comment: @Yatrix It is readable, but it could be more readable by throwing away unneeded chars.

Comment: @AndersLindén To each their own. =)

Answer (score 3):

You have a collection of strings.  The largest string is still a string, not an int.  Since `s.Max()` is a string, and you're assinging it to a variable of type int: `int x = s.Max();` the compiler (correctly) informs you that the types do not match.  You need to convert that string to an int.  Since, looking at your data, they aren't integers, and I see no sensible way of converting those strings into integers, I see no reasonable solution.  What integer should "firstitem" be?

If you just want to execute some code for each item in the array then use one of these patterns:

```
foreach(string item in s)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.website.com/" + item);
}
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.website.com/" + s[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You're missing a couple of semi-colons
2. `x` should presumably be the `Length` of the array, not the largest value in it
3. You need to increment `x` inside of your loop - at the end of it, not outside of it
4. You should actually be incrementing `n`, not `x`
5. `n` should be starting at 0, not at 1
6. Inside the loop you're using `b[0]` where you probably want to use `b[n]`
7. I'm no C++ guru, but I have no idea what `b[]++` might mean
8. As other answers have mentioned, you may want to use a `for` or `foreach` instead of a `while`.
9. Make an effort to go through some introductory tutorials. Trial and error can be a useful tool, but there's no need to fall back on that when learning the very basics

Answer (score 1):

Following is an image to point out what are the errors of your code:

[image: Answer with picture]

After the correction, it would be:

```
int n=1;
string[] s= { "firstitem", "seconditem", "thirditem" };
int x=s.Length;

while(n<x) {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.website.com/"+s[n]);
    n++; // or ++n
}
```

And we can make it more semantic:

```
var items=new[] { "firstitem", "seconditem", "thirditem" };

for(int index=1, count=items.Length; index<count; ++index)
    Process.Start("www.website.com/"+items[index]);
```

If the starting order doesn't matter, and we can use `foreach` instead, and we can use Linq to make the code even simpler:

```
var list=(new[] { "firstitem", "seconditem", "thirditem" }).ToList();
list.ForEach(item => Process.Start("www.website.com/"+item));
```

and we might quite often write in another form:

```
foreach(var item in new[] { "firstitem", "seconditem", "thirditem" })
    Process.Start("www.website.com/"+item);
```

Answer (score 0):

from the sample

```
var processList = (new string[]{"firstitem","seconditem","thirditem"})
                 .Select(s => Process.Start("www.website.com/" + s))
                 .ToList();
```

and here is a test version that outputs to console

```
(new string[] { "firstitem", "seconditem", "thirditem" })
          .Select(s => {  Console.WriteLine(@"www.website.com/" + s); return s; })
          .ToList();
```

note: Select requires a return type and the .ToList() enforces evaluation.

Comment: Question3CPO seemed to be a newcomer in my eyes.

Comment: Linq and Lamdas are some of the great features of c#. I've had good results exposing beginning programmers to it.